# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type Trigger

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql, triggers, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a trigger that only allows data to be inserted or updated if the values are either `'A'` for archived or `'O'` for open. Whenever I run the code, I get a message saying the trigger compiled with errors and then I see the `PLS-00382: expression is of the wrong type error`.

I can't figure out what's wrong. Before, I was using `||` operator instead of `OR` and the trigger compiled without error, but any updates to the table would still raise the exception even if the status was set to `'O'` or `'A'`. I realized that `||` is not the same as `OR` (I have been using Ruby and confused myself). Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Oracle SQL Developer 11g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_status
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF status ON blog_post
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.status != 'O' OR 'A' THEN
    raise_application_error(-20101, 'Value must be A or O, cannot be anything else');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You need either two comparisons (`IF :new.status <> 'O' AND new.status <> 'A'`) or to use a set (`if  not new.status in ('A', 'O')`). The test as you have it written now is `if new.status != ('O' OR 'A')`, and ('O' OR 'A') is a boolean (True or False), which is an invalid test for `new.status`. This is basic SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Ken. I don't know why I did not notice that I only had one comparison in place. After changing the code to the following: IF :new.status != 'O' OR :new.status != 'A'   , the trigger compiled successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate issue is answered in a comment.  You don't have the right syntax for the `if`:

```
IF :new.status not in ('O', 'A') THEN
```

More importantly, though, you don't need a trigger for this.  Instead, just use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table blog_post add constraint chk_status check (status in ('0', 'A'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Gordon, I now understand where I made the error. The instructions for my review stated to create triggers, it did not even occur to me to make a check constraint. Thank you for the advice, I really appreciate it.